# How to upload project build to iPhone in Xcode for testing?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

How do I upload my app in **Xcode** to my **iPhone** for testing?

I have my **iPhone 5** recognized by **Xcode**. When I press the **Run** button - it says `Build succeeded` and nothing happens after that? What do I do next?

How do I test my app on my phone using latest **Xcode**?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or anything else?

Comment: Do you select the target destination as the iPhone? Have you got a developer account registered with apple, from which you have downloaded the necessary provisioning profiles?

Comment: @ZeMoon Yes, it selects my iPhone automatically when I plug it in, and yes I do have a developer license ($99)

I updated the answer and added a screenshot in case that is helpful.

Comment: @anhtu I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Great. You now need to register the iPhone as a test device. For that you need to go to Window > Devices and then press "Use as test device" on the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks, will try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the **"CordovaLib"** beside the run button? You are running the lib, so it can't show anything in your phone. Click on **"CordovaLib"**, and select the target that you want to build.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try.